# How to assign values to the delegate function in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a delegate function in another class, which is shown below

```
Public Class Connect

Public Delegate Function RP_ClientConnect(ByVal hwndClient As IntPtr, _
                                        ByVal deviceID As Short, _
                                        ByVal protocol As String) As Short
```

I have a function in which I am trying to assign the values to the delegate function. But I am not sure of how to do that. I tried but couldn't able to resolve it.

I am trying to pass the new values for deviceID and protocol in delegate function.

```
Private Sub btnConnect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConnect.Click

Dim myNewClientConnect As Connect
Dim iDNumber as Integer= 10
Dim prot as String = "CAN"
myNewClientConnect(Nothing, iDNumber, prot)

End Sub
```

I am new to vb.Net and expecting to get few suggestions from you people.

Comment: your delegate line declares a type - there needs to be a function somewhere which matches that signature.  Then you can declare a var `As RP_ClientConnect` to store the address of that method to the delegate which can be invoked elsewhere, later.  `myDelegate = Addressof(Name of function)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling the delegate, you're calling the constructor of your class.

First, Create a method with the same signature as the delegate:

```
Private Function MyDelegate(ByVal hwndClient As IntPtr, _
                            ByVal deviceID As Short, _
                            ByVal protocol As String) As Short
    'Do something.
End Function
```

Then define a method that creates an instance of the delegate and invokes the method associated with the delegate by calling the built-in Invoke method.

```
Private Sub btnConnect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConnect.Click
    ' Create an instance of the delegate.
    Dim d As RP_ClientConnect = AddressOf MyDelegate
    ' Call the method.
    d.Invoke(Nothing, iDNumber, prot)
End Sub
```

You can refer to this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t38cb9x.aspx) for more details.